# AJAX Timer Control to load a control every 5 secs

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following Hierarchy

> Page
>   -> Usercontrol1 with ( asp:UpdatePanel & asp:Timer)
>   ---> Usercontrol2 with (asp:UpdatePanel) with a grid

In page load i am loading usercontrol1, then usercontrol1 loads usercontrol2.

I am getting following error :-

"Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added"

Now I have tried with

```java
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.UpdatePanel1.Unload += new EventHandler(UpdatePanel_Unload);
}


void UpdatePanel_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.RegisterUpdatePanel(sender as UpdatePanel);
}



public void RegisterUpdatePanel(UpdatePanel panel)
{

    foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in typeof(ScriptManager).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {

        if (methodInfo.Name.Equals("System.Web.UI.IScriptManagerInternal.RegisterUpdatePanel"))
        {

            methodInfo.Invoke(ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page), new object[] { panel });

        }

    }
```

After this i am getting the following error :-

"The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases."

If i remove the update panel from usercontrol2 this works fine... but need an ajax post back in usercontrol2.

Can someone help ?

Thanks
Saif

Comment: DO you really need to use an UpdatePanel for this. It is not really the best way for this sort of thing.

I would recommend looking to do it in JQuery and having the divs either loaded at page load or if they are too big requested through JQuery. Update Panels are not great and even MS have chosen to back JQuery now...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

usercontrol1 has timer_tick event and loads usercontrol2 every 5 secs. 

I would like to handle button click event in usercontrol2, can you please provide an example.

Comment: I have modified my usercontrol2 to perform an jquery ajax call to the page and it works fine now. Thanks for your help.